# Javascript replace key value in object list with user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, lodash, ecmascript-2016

I have an object as below.

```
let data= {
  "" : { name: 'Tom', age: '21'},
  "26": { name: 'Harry', age: '22'}
}
```

The first entry in the list is created when a user clicks on add button to add a new entry.
I take the key value for the first entry from the input field. So if the input value is 8 the new data should be like below.

```
let data= {
  "8" : { name: 'Tom', age: '21'},
  "26": { name: 'Harry', age: '22'}
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So how come you first had key `""`?

Comment: Its just that I am initializing it like that in my react state when a new field is added. So later when the user will put value in the field I want that value to replace there.

Comment: I would store the value in a different state property until you have the key, and only then add the pair to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the new state using destructuring, and then setting the new state:

```js
const updateTempKey = ({ '': temp, ...data }, input) => ({
  ...data,
  [input]: temp
})

const state = {
  "" : { name: 'Tom', age: '21'},
  "26": { name: 'Harry', age: '22'}
}

const newState = updateTempKey(state, '8') 

console.log(newState)
```

Whenever the input is set, you can also set the state of the data:

```
setData(state => updateTempKey(state, input))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `data['some_key']` to be equals `data['']`, than delete `data['']` like below (according to your example):

```
data['8'] = data['']
delete data['']
```